# Alter data source

Tags: sql, powerbi

Power BI can connect to various data sources and run SELECT queries.

Is it possible to run also other queries (INSERT INTO, UPDATE...)?

Now I need it for a postgresql database, but could use also for others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't run directly INSERT/UPDATE queries from Power BI. This isn't the idea of the tool. If you find you need it, then probably there is a major flaw in your design, or you are not using the right tool for this job. But there are few ways to workaround this (again, I'm not saying that you **SHOULD** do it). Usually this is done in a combination with custom written Power App, embedded in your report in [Power Apps visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual). The idea is that the app will write to the database, and will refresh your report after that (if needed).

You can start [here](https://bielite.com/blog/write-back-to-sql-database-from-power-bi/) and I will recommend you to look at this in-depth session - [Writing back data to PowerBI from your reports](https://sqlmasteracademy.com/course/writing-back-data-to-powerbi-from-your-reports/).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it's not the right tool. My database does not have a front end, what type of tools are designed to see data and do modifications?

Comment: They are called "line of business applications" :) Of course you can use some "browser" for your database (SSMS, MySQL Workbench, whatever), but usually is not a good idea to give such powerful tool in the hands of the end user. There are also options to write "no code apps" like Power Apps for example for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **No** if I am very straight forward. PBI is a analysis platform for data. There are probably some advance way to do that but, this is not logical or good idea to think about manipulating data from report or from any BI tools. You can search answers from different blog where the same questions asked. For more details, you can check below links-

1. [help link 1](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-we-insert-Or-Update-records-in-SQL-Server-table-using-Power/td-p/214011)
2. [help link 2](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/12/09/updating-data-in-sql-server-with-power-query/)